# sorting one associative array value by another associative array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-merge

I have question like in the title. I tried to figure it out by myself and searching in the internet but with no result ;/

I have 4 arrays:

```
$sortingArr = array(
    0 => 'EURUSD',
    1 => 'USDGBP'
);

$arr1 = array('name' => 'EURUSD');
$arr2 = array('name' => 'USDPLN');
$arr3 = array('name' => 'USDGBP');
```

and i merged those named arr1, arr2, arr3 as seen below:

```
$data = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
```

How to sort values from $data like 'EURUSD'...  by values from $sortingArr.

I hope I explained this clearly and pls be understanding coz its my first post here:)

Comment: What's your expected output? Should `USDPLN` be between `EURUSD` and `USDGBP` or after it?

Comment: i want to get $data array sorted by $sortingArr like this:

'EURUSD',
'USDGBP',
'USDPLN'

now i have:

'EURUSD',
'USDPLN',
'USDGBP',

Comment: Your expect output follows basic sorting alphabetically, why not just `sort($mergedarray)`? Example https://eval.in/654407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the function to sort an array by values of another array

```
<?php
    //sorting array
    $sortingArr = array(
    0 => 'EURUSD',
    1 => 'USDGBP',
);
$arr1 = array('name' => 'EURUSD');
$arr2 = array('name' => 'USDPLN');
$arr3 = array('name' => 'USDGBP');
// to be sorted array
$data = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
// calling a custom function
$new_data = sortArrayByArrayValue($data['name'],$sortingArr);
print_r($new_data); // print results 

function sortArrayByArrayValue($array, $orderArray) {
    $ordered = array();
    // loop the array
    foreach ($orderArray as $key=>$value) {
        // check the value is in the $array
        if (($k = array_search($value, $array)) !== false) {
            // assign thet value to new array
            $ordered[$k] = $array[$k];
            // unset the value
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
    return $ordered+ $array;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => EURUSD
    [2] => USDGBP
    [1] => USDPLN
)
```

Comment: its correct. or you can use return array_merge($ordered,$array); Do you still have issue ?